# How can I make 3d plots of planes by using spreadsheet in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, spreadsheet

```
pointA=[9.62579 15.7309 3.3291];
pointB=[13.546  25.6869 3.3291];
pointC=[23.502  21.7667 -3.3291];
pointD=[19.5818 11.8107 -3.3291];

points=[pointA' pointB' pointC' pointD'];
fill3(points(1,:),points(2,:),points(3,:),'r')
grid on
alpha(0.3)
```

This code will show a filled plane(Cant add images yet T.T)

Now here is my problem. On a spreadsheet, I have x,y,z coordinates of thousands of points. The 4 consecutive points form a plane like the one shown. How do I make a code such that for every 4 consecutive points, it makes a filled plane.
Basically, if I have 400 points, I want the code to plot 100 planes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data are a matrix, m = (400,3)

`m = rand(400,3); 
  for i = 1:length(m);
    m2 = m'; % Transpose 
  end`

Create a 3-D matrix in which 'j' represents each set of points:

```
m3=[];
```

%Not the most elegant way to cycle through every four points but it works!

```
z = 0:(length(m2)/4); z1 = (z*4)+1; z1 = z1(:,1:length(z)-1); 
    for j = 1:length(z1);
        m3(:,:,j) = m2(:,z1(j):(z1(j)+3));
    end
```

'j' now has a total length = 100 - representing the amount planes;

```
fill3(m3(1,:,1),m3(2,:,1),m3(3,:,1),'r');
```

% Cycle through planes- make a new figure for each plane;

```
for j = 1:length(z1);
    fill3(m3(1,:,j),m3(2,:,j),m3(3,:,j),'r'); 
end
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by making 3D matrix.. can u help me

Comment: So we made a multi-dimensional array that is row x column x page.  It's a way to organize/access your data.  Check out this help page, it gives a pretty good explanation:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html

Comment: i.e. m3 is a 3D-array that contains rows of x,y,z coordinates, columns containing the points A,B,C,D respectively, and each consecutive
page has the next set of 4 points (with their x,y,z coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

```
clear all, close all, clc
pointA=rand(99,1);
pointB=rand(99,1);
pointC=rand(99,1);
pointD=rand(99,1);
pointAmat = reshape(pointA,3,1,[]);
pointBmat = reshape(pointB,3,1,[]);
pointCmat = reshape(pointC,3,1,[]);
pointDmat = reshape(pointD,3,1,[]);

points=[pointAmat pointBmat pointCmat pointDmat];

for i = 1:size(points,3)
fill3(points(1,:,i),points(2,:,i),points(3,:,i),'r')
hold all
end
grid on
alpha(0.3)
```

Hope this helps.