# plot multiple 3D rectangles in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, 3d

I have an array of data points of size 400x3 (400 points with x,y,z coordinates).
Each group of 4 consecutive points represent the corners of a rectangle,
so there are 100 rectangles (finite planes).

I would like to plot all 100 rectangles in 3D, but I am very new to matlab.

So far I am able to plot a single rectangle:

```
% A sample rectangle
pointB=[16.1445 20.0025 1.64238];
pointC=[21.7378 29.1242 1.64238];
pointD=[30.8595 23.5309 -1.64238];
pointE=[25.2662 14.4092 -1.64238];

% Plot in 3D
points=[pointB' pointC' pointD' pointE'];
fill3(points(1,:),points(2,:),points(3,:),'r')
grid on
alpha(0.3)
```

So how do I repeat this for the remaining rectangles.. help!

Comment: isn't that the same question than your previous one : [How can I make 3d plots of planes by using spreadsheet in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185995/how-can-i-make-3d-plots-of-planes-by-using-spreadsheet-in-matlab) ?

Comment: Hehe. No, the numbers are different.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
% Load sample points
pointB=[16.1445 20.0025 1.64238];
pointC=[21.7378 29.1242 1.64238];
pointD=[30.8595 23.5309 -1.64238];
pointE=[25.2662 14.4092 -1.64238];

% The dimensions of points are now BCDE(4) x XYZ(3) x shapes(1)
points = [pointB; pointC; pointD; pointE];
size(points)
% Permute the dimensions for fill3 BCDE(4) x shapes(1) x XYZ(3)
points = permute(points, [1 3 2]);
size(points)

% Make some simulated rectangles (you would load these from a file)
% We will add to XYZ, making copies along the 2nd (shapes) dimension
% offset is 1 x shapes(11) x XYZ(3)
offset = permute([0:10:100; 0:10:100; 0:1:10], [3 2 1]);
% The dimensions of points are now BCDE(4) x shapes(11) x XYZ(3)
points = bsxfun(@plus, points, offset);
size(points)

% Extract X,Y,Z, so each is BCDE(4) x shapes(11)
X = points(:,:,1);
Y = points(:,:,2);
Z = points(:,:,3);

% Plot
fill3(X, Y, Z, 'r');
grid on;
alpha(0.3);
```